# Can we prove a trinomial distribution approaches a Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, binomial-distribution, gaussian, multinomial-distribution

Consider a random walk with trinomial distribution where $i^{th}$ step is a random variable $X_i$ takes values $-\frac{1}{i}, 0, \frac{1}{i}$ with probability $0.3, 0.4, 0.3$ respectively. (A simpler problem may deal with $X_i$ taking values $-1, 0, +1$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ each).

My intuition is that probability distribution for $S_n = \sum_{i \le n} X_i$ is likely a Gaussian. I started by following the template of proof for how the binomial distribution tends to a Gaussian for large n but am having trouble even at the first step when writing equation for $\mathbb{P}(S_n = m)$. Any ideas for how to prove or disprove of this? Thanks!

Comment: @hardmath yes. The drunkard is getting tired with each step.

Comment: The references in [this paper](http://article.sapub.org/10.5923.j.materials.20150502.05.html), "A Note on Random Walks with Varying Step Sizes" by Gopinath Subrumanian (2015, Amer. J. of Materials Science), may be helpful.  Many treatments of varying step sizes involve *geometric progression* unlike your problem.

Comment: This [1998 paper](https://aimath.org/~morrison/Research/RandomWalks.pdf) by Kent Morrison, "Random Walks with Decreasing Steps," analyzes the *binomial* version of your walk, which he calls *harmonic random walk* (i.e. staying in place at turns has zero probability).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $k$-th step has a mean of $\mathbb{E}[X_k] = 0$ and a variance of $\text{Var}[X_k] = \mathbb{E}[X_k^2]-\mathbb{E}[X_k]^2 = \dfrac{0.6}{k^2}$.

Then, $S := \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}X_k$ has a mean of $\mathbb{E}[S] = 0$, and since the steps $X_k$ are independent, $\text{Var}[S] = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\text{Var}[X_k] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{0.6}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{10}$, where we used the well-known sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$.

The characteristic function of a Gaussian random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is $e^{i\mu t - \sigma^2t^2/2}$. So if $S$ is Gaussian, its characteristic function $\mathbb{E}[e^{itS}]$ must be $e^{-\pi^2t^2/20}$.

Using the Taylor series expansion $\ln(0.4+0.6\cos x) = -0.3x^2-0.02x^4+O(x^6)$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\ln(0.4+0.6\cos x) < -0.3x^2$ for all $x \in (0,\delta)$. Then, for any $t \in (0,\delta)$, we have:
\begin{align*} 
\mathbb{E}[e^{itS}] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(it\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}X_k\right)\right]
\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}e^{itX_k}\right]
\\
&= \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{itX_k}\right]
\\
&= \prod_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left(0.4+0.6\cos\left(\dfrac{t}{k}\right) \right)
\\
&= \exp\left[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\ln\left(0.4+0.6\cos\left(\dfrac{t}{k}\right) \right)\right]
\\
&< \exp\left[\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}-0.3 \dfrac{t^2}{k^2}\right]
\\
&= \exp\left[-\dfrac{\pi^2t^2}{20}\right],
\end{align*}
where the inequality step holds by applying the inequality $\ln(0.4+0.6\cos x) < -0.3x^2$ for $x = \dfrac{t}{k}$.

Since $S$ has mean $0$, variance $\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}$, but its characteristic function is not $e^{-\pi^2t^2/20}$, $S$ is not Gaussian.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the fourth equality, I am having trouble comprehending it. $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_k} ] = 0.4 + \cos(t/k)$ I believe you are using Euler's identity.

Comment: Sure, I totally skipped that derivation. Using the definition of expected value, $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_k}] = 0.3e^{it \cdot 1/k}+0.4e^{it \cdot 0}+0.3e^{it \cdot -1/k}$ which we can simplify to $0.4+0.6\cos\tfrac{t}{k}$ using the identity $\cos \theta = (e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2$.

Comment: Great. Makes sense.